# How to use ostringstream as a default argument?

Tags: c++11

I have a function

`func(parameter 1, parameter 2);`

Now, I'm trying to add additional functionality for which I want to pass ostringstream as a 3rd parameter.

`func(parameter 1, parameter 2, ostringstream& abc);`

The problem is this function is called many times in codebase and in some places it is to be called without ostringstream.

So, I was trying to set default parameter for ostringstream but can't find a way.

Can somebody help? Don't worry about function body, I'm making sure that I do not use ostringstream if it wasn't present while calling the function.

Comment: Instead of a default argument, write two overloads. Have the two-parameter overload define an `ostringstream` variable, then pass it to the three-parameter overload that does the actual work.

Comment: Thanks, I think this would work. Now, I remember I saw similar approach to overload std::string and char[] but it didn't occur to me.

Comment: As a side note, there's `std::optional` that could be useful when overloading is too cumbersome.